# "Error in int_abline...plot.new has not been called yet"

Tags: r, plot

I've seen this error posted elsewhere here, but I've not gotten any of the fixes to work. I'm currently using the built-in "faithful" dataset as part of the r-tutor.com tutorial:

```
duration = faithful$eruptions
waiting = faithful$waiting
abline(lm(duration ~ waiting))
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I tried `plot.new()`, no luck. 
I tried

```
x <- (duration ~ waiting)
abline(x)
```

no luck.

I tried re-starting R, no luck. Using 3.0.0 for Windows.
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`abline` has to be called on an existing plot. You can't call it when nothing has been plotted.

You probably wanted to do this:

```
plot(duration ~ waiting, data=faithful)
abline(lm(duration ~ waiting, data=faithful))
```

Comment: I'd already defined the variables from the data, but you're right about plot. Now I understand, thanks.

Comment: I know this is old, but I had a similar issue, and simply adding a "+" after to the plot command works too!

Answer (score 11):

Adding a `+` after your plot command will work. I worked for me.

```
plot(y~x) + abline()
```

credit to Gabriel (2nd comment on the above solution). Though I should post it because usually I do not read the comments and since I am new it would not allow me to thank her. So I thought I should post it as an answer. Thanks, Gabriel. It worked for me as well.